# Prove that the sum of a sequence diverges

Tags: calculus

Suppose that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfies $ 0 < a_n \le a_{2n} + a_{2n+1}$ for all $n \ge 1$. Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Comment: Why should we? Of what interest is this question? Where did it come from, what do you know about it, what approaches have you already tried? Give us something to go on.

Comment: Also,there's no explicit formulas here,so the usual convergence tests for series would be of very little use.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$. Since the terms $a_n$ are positive, $s_n$ is monotonic increasing. Furthermore, $s_n \le s_{2n+1} - a_1$ for all $n\ge 1$. Indeed,

$$s_1 = a_1 \le a_2 + a_3 = s_3 - a_1 = s_{2(1)+1}-a_1$$

and if $s_n \le s_{2n+1} - a_1$ for some $n > 1$, then

$$s_{n+1} = s_n + a_{n+1} \le s_{2n+1} - a_1 + a_{2n+2} + a_{2n+3} = s_{2n+3} - a_1 = s_{2(n+1)+1}-a_1$$

Hence by induction, $s_n \le s_{2n+1} - a_1$ for all $n \ge 2$.

Set $\epsilon = a_1$. Given a positive integer $N$, set $m = 2N+1$ and $n = N$. Then $m, n \ge N$ and $|s_m - s_n| = s_{2N+1} - s_N \ge a_1 = \epsilon$. Therefore, by the Cauchy criterion, $s_n$ diverges, i.e., $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Comment: +1 I overthought this as usual. I considered the Cauchy criterion,but it seemed too simple.